# m2m django implementation after following a tutorial

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, m2m

Scenario: I have some boxes (containers) I have some objects (samples) a sample can be split over many boxes, a box can contain many samples.

I want to be able to assign a sample to a box and remove a sample from a box.

I followed these [tutorials 57-59](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLZlyjq_mFc&list=PLw02n0FEB3E3VSHjyYMcFadtQORvl1Ssj&index=59), assigning friends to users, and got it working.

So I now try to adapt the code, so I need to change users to boxes/containers and friends to samples. Sounds simple enough. But I'm inexperienced with the quirks of Django and where the `request.user` is I can't seem to get the correct syntax. So here comes the code, first the code working from the tutorial, then my attempt at refactoring it.

I have 2 other tables/models Containers and Sample which the ContainerContent model fits inbetween.

```
# models.py (tutorial)
class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    # container_id = models.ForeignKey(Container, null=True, on_delete = models.PROTECT)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)

    @classmethod
    def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.remove(new_friend)


# views.py
def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
    friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        Friend.make_friend(request.user, friend)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        Friend.lose_friend(request.user, friend)

    return redirect('depot:allcontainer')


#urls.py
url(r'^container/(?P<operation>.*)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.change_friends, name='change_friends'),


#html
...
        <tbody>
          {% for user in users %}
          <tr>
            {% if user not in friends %}
            <!-- we will want to add an if stmt list if not in unassigned - need to think how to do this -->
            <td>{{ container.container_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
            <td>  <a href="{% url 'depot:change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}"  class="badge badge-primary" role="button">
              <!-- container=container.container_id -->
              <!-- container=container.container_id -->
              <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">add</button> -->
              >>
            </a></td>
            {% endif %}
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
...

...
      <tbody>
      <tr>
          {% for friend in friends %}
          <td><a href="{% url 'depot:change_friends'  operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}" class="badge badge-primary" role="button">
            <<
          </a></td>
          <td>{{ friend.username }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
...
```

**Below is my Attempt:**

```
# models.py
class ContainerContents(models.Model):
    sample = models.ManyToManyField('Sample')
    current_container = models.ForeignKey(Container, null=True, on_delete = models.PROTECT)

        @classmethod
        def add_to_container(cls, current_container, new_sample):
            sample, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
                current_container=current_container
            )
            sample.add(new_sample)

        @classmethod
        def remove_from_container(cls, current_container, new_sample):
            sample, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
                current_container=current_container
            )
            sample.remove(new_sample)

# views.py - this one is causing me issues, the request.____
def change_container(request, operation, pk, fk='', sample_id=''):
    container = Container.objects.get(pk=pk)
    sample = Sample.objects.get(pk=fk)
    # sample = Container.objects.get(container.sample_id=sample_id)
    if operation == 'add':
        ContainerContents.add_to_container(request.container, container)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        ContainerContents.remove_from_container(request.container, container)

    return redirect('depot:allcontainer')

# urls.py
url(r'^change_container/(?P<operation>.*)/(?P<pk>\d+)/sample/(?P<fk>\d+)$', views.change_container, name='change_container'),
```

I suspect I need to pass the container id here otherwise there will not be any distinction between the containers.

```
# html
    <tbody>
      {% for unassigned in container_contents %}
      <tr>
        <!-- { if user not in friends } -->
        <!-- we will want to add an if stmt list if not in unassigned - need to think how to do this -->
        <td>{{ unassigned.area_easting }}.
          {{ unassigned.area_northing }}.
          {{ unassigned.context_number }}.
          {{ unassigned.sample_number }}</td>
          <td>{{ unassigned.sample_id }}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>  <a href="{ url 'depot:change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk }"  class="badge badge-primary" role="button">
            <!-- container=container.container_id -->
            <!-- container=container.container_id -->
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">add</button> -->
            >>
          </a></td>
          <!-- { endif } -->
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
...
...

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        {% for contents in container_contents %}
        <td><a href="{% url 'depot:change_container'  operation='remove' pk=container.container_id fk=contents.sample_id  %}" class="badge badge-primary" role="button">
          <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">remove</button> -->
          <<
        </a></td>
        <td>{{ contents.sample_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ contents.area_easting }}.
          {{ contents.area_northing }}.
          {{ contents.context_number }}.
          {{ contents.sample_number }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
...
```

--- Update ---

I should have included the view that generates the page, not the users/friends is still contained in it and will be removed once I get it working.

```
def detailcontainer(request, container_id):
    container = get_object_or_404(Container, pk=container_id)
    samples = container.samples.all()
    # allsamples = container.samples.exclude(sample_id=samples)
    allsamples = container.samples.all()

    users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).order_by('-id')
    friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
    friends = friend.users.all().order_by('-id')

    container_contents = container.samples.all()
    # container_contents = Container.objects.get(current_container=samples)

    return render(request, 'container/detailcontainer.html',
    {'container':container,
    'samples':samples,
    'allsamples': allsamples,

    'users': users,
    'friends': friends,

    'container_contents': container_contents,

    })
```

Comment: Did you try `ContainerContents.add_to_container(container, sample)`?

Comment: I've added an update to include the view which controls the page.

Comment: I just tested it locally and it works just fine. Do you still have problems? What error does it produce?

Comment: There is no error, but the item is not removed from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should cause issues because `request` does not have any attribute named container. In your tutorial example, it got the **logged in user** using `request.user`, because django assigns logged in user instance to the `request`(through middleware).

As you already have `sample` and `container` objects in your `change_container` view method, you can try like this:

```
if operation == 'add':
    ContainerContents.add_to_container(container, sample)
elif operation == 'remove':
    ContainerContents.remove_from_container(container, sample)
```

#### Update

Missed one thing, you need to change inside `add_to_container` and `remove_from_container` method as well:

```
    @classmethod
    def add_to_container(cls, current_container, new_sample):
        container, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_container=current_container
        )
        container.sample.add(new_sample)

    @classmethod
    def remove_from_container(cls, current_container, new_sample):
        container, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_container=current_container
        )
        container.sample.remove(new_sample)
```

Because sample is a ManyToMany Field making connection between `CurrentContainer` and `Sample` model.

#### Update 2

```
@classmethod
def remove_from_container(cls, current_container, new_sample):
     from app_name.models import ContainerSample

     c_sample = ContainerSample.objects.get(container=current_container, sample=new_sample)
     c_sample.delete()
```

Comment: This gives the error:  `'ContainerContents' object has no attribute 'remove'`
I tested sample and container in the shell, they both have objects assigned.

Comment: @GaryNobles please see the update section of my answer

Comment: ok, so the redirect is working but the data does not change, I've added the update code here: https://dpaste.de/rS5x

Comment: How did you check if data is changed or not?

Comment: Through the template, the `{% for contents in container_contents %}` should not list the sample if it has been removed from the container.

Comment: Ah, ok I wasn't calling the list of all samples correctly `unassigned = Sample.objects.all()` this is then returned `'unassigned': unassigned` but still not adding to the container_contents

Comment: I went through and cleaned up the code, there was some table naming issues. I looked in the database, in the through table the container is successfully added when I click to add a sample, but I get the error `ContainerSamples has no sample.` In the trace it shows `sample_id''`

Here's the current code: https://dpaste.de/XYc8 (I'll update the question if a solution is found)

Comment: ok, so I solved the add function, but the remove is giving me the following error: `remove_from_container() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sample'`

Comment: sorry, you need to share code for what you have tried for removing container

Comment: Sorry,  try to avoid putting code through dpaste, but this is a code heavy question. Here is the latest code elements: https://dpaste.de/sgPF

Comment: You need to add `@classmethod` on top of 'remove_from_container' method(same as add method)

Comment: Thanks! That has solved the sample error (can't believe I missed that!) But now getting `Cannot query "29265877": Must be "Container" instance.`  29265877 is a sample in container 11

Comment: Please change `.remove_from_container(sample, container)` to `.remove_from_container(container, sample)`

Comment: hmmm, `Cannot use remove() on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use depot.ContainerSamples's Manager instead.`

Comment: I replaced the whole def with you amendment, now I'm getting `name 'ContainerSample' is not defined` thank you for helping me with this m2m seems a real pain.

Comment: Ah, I had renamed `ContainerSample` to `ContainerSamples` thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing your m2m field in fetched object. You'll need to address `sample` field as following:

models.py:

```py
@classmethod
def add_to_container(cls, current_container, new_sample):
    containerContents, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
        current_container=current_container
    )
    containerContents.sample.add(new_sample)

@classmethod
def remove_from_container(cls, current_container, new_sample):
    containerContents, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
        current_container=current_container
    )
    containerContents.sample.remove(new_sample)
```

and set proper variables to your model methods:

views.py

```py
def change_container(request, operation, pk, fk='', sample_id=''):
    container = Container.objects.get(pk=pk)
    sample = Sample.objects.get(pk=fk)
    # sample = Container.objects.get(container.sample_id=sample_id)
    if operation == 'add':
        ContainerContents.add_to_container(container, sample)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        ContainerContents.remove_from_container(container, sample)

    return redirect('depot:allcontainer')
```

Comment: I went through and cleaned up the code, there was some table naming issues. I looked in the database, in the through table the container is successfully added when I click to add a sample, but I get the error `ContainerSamples has no sample.` In the trace it shows `sample_id''`

Here's the current code: https://dpaste.de/XYc8 (I'll update the question if a solution is found)